# Sliding drawer top offset dynamically not working properly for landscape and portrait

Tags: java, android

I am having problem with `sliding drawer` top offset while setting dynamically for `landscape` and `portrait`.It is not taking different values from values-land because I have used `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` because the requirement is for `landscape` and `portrait` both.

Here is my code

```
 <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rel_bottom"
            android:content="@+id/side_panel"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:topOffset="@dimen/sliding_drawer_top_offset">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.customViews.ChatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_handle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_details_bar_to_tap"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:rotation="0"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/xxxsmall_padding"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_handle"
                    android:background="@color/slidingDrawer_line_color" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </SlidingDrawer>
```

As per my design requirement I have used in values-port ,

```
<dimen name="sliding_drawer_top_offset">140dp</dimen>
```

For values-land,

```
<dimen name="sliding_drawer_top_offset">0dp</dimen>
```

Any idea how to solve it.

Comment: What is 'values-land' and 'values-port' ? I don't recall ports being used as jargon in Android xml files.

Comment: I have removed values-port now there is only "values " and "Values-land". Still its not working.